# Is it possible to determine $|\sin x|\le |x|$ using these 4 axioms about $\sin$ and $\cos$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

In Apostol's Calculus Vol. $1$, it is stated that the all relevant properties of the trignometric functions can be derived from the following 4 axioms:

> (1) Sine and cosine functions are defined everywhere on the real line.
>
> (2) Special values: $\cos 0 = \sin(\pi/2) = 1, \; \cos \pi = -1.$
>
> (3) $\cos(y - x) = \cos y \cos x + \sin y \sin x.$
>
> (4) For $0 < x < \pi/2$: $\displaystyle 0 < \cos x < \frac{\sin x}{x} < \frac{1}{\cos x}.$

However, to prove $|\sin x|\le |x|$, which is to be used in a proof of the continuity of $\sin$, he resorts to the geometric definition of $\sin$ and $\cos$. Is it possible to prove this result using just these 4 axioms?

Comment: Considering that $|\frac{sinx}{x}|≤1$ is obtained from the series expansion of sine function, i doubt if it's possible.

Comment: It has to be possible, because all subsequent results, such as the Taylor Series for $~\sin(x)~$ are consequences of these axioms.  Further, the question that you are raising is directly answered by the Taylor Series.

Comment: @RAHUL See my previous comment.

Comment: "However, to prove..." : Your last paragraph is wrong, and represents a misinterpretation of what Apostol is doing.  See my comment, following the answer of TurlocTheRed.

Comment: @user2661923 I don't see how my question is wrong. Just because the geometric definitions satisfy these axioms doesn't mean that it is possible to derive the required result from the axioms alone. Might it not be possible that the geometric definitions introduce some extra information not contained within the 4 axioms themselves?

Comment: In "Calculus" 2nd Edition, Volume 1, Apostol does in fact manually derive all of the standard results, including derivatives and Taylor series, just from axioms 1 through 4.  This is the whole point of his approach.  The discussion of the geometric version of the trig functions, per Apostol's approach, has absolutely no analytical significance, other than to demonstrate that there exists at least one example of the sine and cosine functions that do in fact satisfy the axioms.  This implies that the axioms are not impossible to satisfy, and so (among other things) are not self-contradictory.

Comment: As an indirect *learning crutch*, for students in transition from trignometry to real analysis, you also have that since the geometric versions of the sine and cosine functions (with the domains adjusted) do in fact satisfy the axioms, this implies that the geometric versions **inherit** all of the results that are derived analytically, just from the axioms.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $0 \le x \le \pi/2$.

$0< \cos x < \frac{\sin x}{x}<\frac{1}{\cos x}$

$0<x \cos x < \sin x < x\sec x$

$0<x\cos^2 x < \sin x \cos x < x$

$0<2x\cos ^2 x < \sin 2x < 2x$

Let $u=2x$

$0<u\cos^2 (u/2) < \sin u < u$.

$-u< - \sin u < 0$

$- \sin u = \sin (-u)$

So if $u< 0$, that expression becomes $u<\sin u< 0$

---

I'm not sure how justified it is to use #4 as an axiom. They derive from geometric properties, so I'd think they were theorems. Those geometric properties offer a more direct route to the result.

If the hypotenuse of a right triangle is the radius of a unit circle with one vertex at the center, the portion of the circle subtended by the acute angle at the center is longer than the sine of the right triangle by the triangle inequality. The arc has length $x$ where $x$ is the measure of the acute angle in radians. It follows $\forall x \ge 0, 0\le \sin x \le x$. The other half follows by  symmetry so $0\le |\sin x| \le |x|$

Comment: Apostol's approach is to start with the axioms, including #4, and then indicate that the geometric definitions of sine and cosine satisfy the axioms, as long as the domain of the sine and cosine functions are changed from angles to unit circle arc lengths.